# Can I earn achievements while offline?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I will be traveling for 2 days very soon and will not be online. Can I play the single player campaign and earn achievements during this time? (i.e. - do they sync later?)

Or must I **always** be online when I play X-Com: EU? (that'd be lame!)

Comment: From looking around, it seems it depends on specific game implementation, not Steam itself - people say it works for some games and doesn't for others. I guess someone needs to test XCOM specifically...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it does work. I've been playing XCOM with Steam running in offline mode. I've got achievements, and they got synced to Steam once I got online.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you will automatically get the achievements when you 'reconnect' to steam.

But I do know you can 'save' games and load them later. So if you 'save' your games just before you get a known achievement (i.e. before you finish a specific mission, or research the last item) - then you can just reload those games when you come back, and get that specific achievement.